# document.getelementbyid vs dom.byid

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is some code

```
  var docDiv= document.getElementById("divId");

  var dojoDiv= dom.byId("divId");
```

what are difference between javascript's document.getelementbyid and dojo's dom.byid. which is one more faster. if you want to use dom we need to load dojo.js.

Comment: `document.getElementById("divId")` is faster !

Comment: Why document.getElementById is faster? which one is i should used?

Comment: Because `dom.byId()` is a wrapper for native JS `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` is faster than `dom.byId()`. because `dom.byId()` need to load dojo core files.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the non IE version of Dojo's dom.byId :

```
dom.byId = function(id, doc){
            // inline'd type check.
            // be sure to return null per documentation, to match IE branch.
            return ((typeof id == "string") ? (doc || win.doc).getElementById(id) : id) || null; // DOMNode
        };
```

As you will note it uses getElementById.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think  `document.getElementById()` is faster than `dom.byId()` because dojo is internally using 
`document`.

Answer (score 0):

from dojo github code https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dom.js#L51 , which uses `document.getElementById` internally

```
dom.byId = function(id, doc){
    // inline'd type check.
    // be sure to return null per documentation, to match IE branch.
    return ((typeof id == "string") ? (doc || win.doc).getElementById(id) : id) || null; // DOMNode
};
```

using `document.getElementById` , we can avoid calling this `dom.byId` function !.. but performance difference is very less

I prefer `dom.byId`, because it is short to use. otherwise I have to write lengthy `document.getElementById` in every where !